# How to Initialize LSTMCell with tuple

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I recently upgraded my tesnorflow from Rev8 to Rev12. In Rev8 the default "state_is_tuple" flag in rnn_cell.LSTMCell is set to False, so I initialized my LSTM Cell with an list, see code below.

```
#model definition  
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.config.hidden_dim)
outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, data, initial_state=self.init_state)


#init_state place holder and feed_dict
def add_placeholders(self):
     self.init_state = tf.placeholder("float", [None, self.cell_size])

def get_feed_dict(self, data, label):
    feed_dict = {self.input_data: data,
             self.input_label: reg_label,
             self.init_state: np.zeros((self.config.batch_size, self.cell_size))}
    return feed_dict
```

In Rev12, the default "state_is_tuple" flag is set to True, in order to make my old code work I had to explicitly turn the flag to False. However, now I got an warning from tensorflow saying:

> "Using a concatenated state is slower and will soon be deprecated. 
>   Use state_is_tuple=True"

I tried to initialize LSTM cell with a tuple by changing the placeholder definition for self.init_state to the following:

```
self.init_state = tf.placeholder("float", (None, self.cell_size))
```

but now I got an error message saying:

> "'Tensor' object is not iterable"

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: The tuple is a complicated structure unfortunately. Do you *have to* explicitely make the `init_state` a placeholder? It would be much better to use `cell.zero_state` instead. Don't worry, you can pass the state in `feed_dict` across runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding a "zero state" to an LSTM is much simpler now using [`cell.zero_state`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/base_interface_for_all_rnn_cells#RNNCell.zero_state). You do not need to explicitely define the initial state as a placeholder. Define it as a tensor instead and feed it if required. This is how it works,

```
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(self.config.hidden_dim)
self.initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, data, initial_state=self.init_state)
```

If you wish to feed some other value as the initial state, Let's say `next_state = states[-1]` for instance, calculate it in your session and pass it in the `feed_dict` like -

```
feed_dict[self.initial_state] = next_state
```

In the context of your question, `lstm_cell.zero_state()` should suffice.

---

Unrelated, but remember that you can pass both Tensors and Placeholders in the feed dictionary! That's how `self.initial_state` is working in the example above. Have a look at the [PTB Tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb) for a working example.